# Type hinting for ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, type-hinting

Can I type hint a *ctype* type?

```
from ctypes import *

def wrap_function(library: str, name: str, restype, argtypes) -> *What goes here*:
    """Simplify wrapping ctypes functions"""
    func = library.__getattr__(name)
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    return func
```

Checking *ctypes* functions I've created before I get `<_FuncPtr object at 0x--------->`. How would I indicate this in python?

I tried

```
ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.CFUNCTYPE)
```

but it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be a ctypes type
```

Comment: dunder functions aren't meant to be called directly.  Use `getattr(library,name)`.

Comment: Since your function wrapper can wrap anything, `Callable` would work as a return value type hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFUNCTYPE` is a function prototype not a `ctypes` type.
You can use `CFUNCTYPE` to define a function type and then wrap it in a pointer e.g.

```
from ctypes import *
POINTER(CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int)))
```

You can use the defined type to type hint. I see you are trying to "simplify" wrapping. But you can't introduce static types when the purpose of your function is to return functions with dynamic types.